# Visual bug on tabs covering badge tracker

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page, user-interface

There's a bug where the tabs in the Activity screen overlap the badge tracker section and it hides the "Track the next one" link. Chrome 69.0.3497.100 on OSX 10.14 Mojave.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, people have been noticing this on all sites throughout the Stack Exchange network. There's a 'central' [bug post on the Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316061/295232) which has [now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/316061/revisions) been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), meaning it should be resolved.